# Android 13 - What happens to photos in OneDrive/Google Photos that were backed up once you delete a photo from your storage?

Tags: samsung, photos, onedrive, android-13

I'm on android 13 with the Samsung a32 5g.

If I delete a photo on my phone that was synced to OneDrive or Google Photos backup and sync again, will that photo automatically get deleted after 30 days, or will the backup stay indefinitely?

I know deleting files on PC and resyncing removes them from OneDrive, so I'm wondering if the same goes for mobile and what happens for Google Photos.

Comment: OneDrive is not Google Photos... The two behave very differently. I can't speak to OneDrive (don't use it at all) but Google Photos is essentially a photo archiving service, if you delete a picture from your phone, it will continue to be in the GP archive, UNLESS you delete it with Google Photo, and in which case it specifically tells you "Delete from your account and all devices linked to it", or something to that effect... If you factory reset your phone, or delete the files with a file manager from the camera's photo directory for example, the files will still exist in GP.

Comment: I don't know about OneDrive, but for Google Photos, if the photos are deleted from outside the Photos app, then they will stay indefinitely (as mentioned in [my previous answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/249384/44325), only files *on the device* that are deleted after <s>30</s> 60 days). If it's from the Photos app, then there are 2 types of deletions: "Delete" (the trash can icon, delete from both device and backup), and "Delete from device" (the crossed phone icon, delete only from the device, backup stays indefinitely)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you, so for sure Google Drive photos stay after being deleted on just the phone device, but as for OneDrive I'm not sure but could function the same way.